# Smooth Scrolling and Scroll Animation

Tags: jquery, scroll, smoothing

I'm wondering how to do this effects: www.yaswaterworld.com
Coz' when I scroll on that website, it has delay and smooth effect.

I already tried the Scroll Magic: http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic

Please help.

Thanks!